# Installing Python and openCV during macOS Application Installer

Tags: python, swift, macos

I am building a desktop application using `Swift 5`. Its an image processing and manipulation application. For this purpose, I need to use `Python3.7` with `OpenCV`.

The project is complete. I downloaded `Python3.7` and pip installed openCV on my terminal. And executed the commands using `PythonKit`.

What needs to be when I ship the desktop application on my website. How would these dependencies be installed by the installer? What is the quickest way to download and install these dependencies during the mac OS installer phase?

Comment: did you make a google search and tried following instructions? if so, please share where did you get stuck

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Using file requirements.txt for store content of requirement dependencies

You need to put all requirements of dependencies for up and run your application in one file called **requriements.txt** and then use pip to install them all.

Examples: if you've only a dependency just put type command to install by pip

`$ pip install gphoto2`

or put it in file **requriements.txt**

```
gphoto2
flask
requests
```

and then type the command:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

Note: The file requirements.txt need to put in the root directory of project.

Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file

**Option 2:** Put it in steup.py if your application will be packaging.

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE", # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=['gphoto2','requests',...]
)
```

Reference: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

**Option 3:** Write shell script for automating install (Advance)

You need to understand shell script syntax for build automates script to install dependencies. example

create a file be **setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo "Welcome to setup Application xxxx"
#args not set

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then

    echo -n "Please enter the database name : "
    read db_name
    echo -n "Please enter the file name : "
    read db_file_name
else
    db_name=$1
    db_file_name=$2
fi
echo "Database connection close ....."
echo ""
```

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: I got the same problem, and this works well for me, thanks :)